Minor terminology improvement for the AI policy
https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/ai-policy, https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/ai-policy, https://superuser.com/help/ai-policy, https://serverfault.com/help/ai-policy, etc. state:

Generative artificial intelligence (a.k.a. GPT, LLM, generative AI, genAI) tools can be used

That's a bit incorrect. I propose this more correct phrasing:

Generative artificial intelligence (a.k.a. generative AI or genAI) tools such as GPT or other LLMs can be used.


Shouldn't this be posted on physics.meta and webapps?

@Mari-LouAСлаваУкраїні idk who write these policies but looks like it's a template many SE sites copied/adapted. https://serverfault.com/help/ai-policy, https://superuser.com/help/ai-policy, etc.

This isn't a valid change.
GPT stands for "generative pre-trained transformer", a specific type of LLM, or large language model. One application of LLMs is in generative AI, which is sometimes shortened to genAI.
Technically, it's incorrect to call LLMs "generative AI". Although LLMs can be used for generation, they can also be used for classification and other tasks. GPTs are a subset of LLMs specifically designed for generation tasks.
A better change would be:

Generative artificial intelligence (a.k.a. generative AI, genAI) tools can be used

This removes the incorrect implication that LLMs must be generative in nature. Removing GPT also broadens the scope to include image, video, and audio generation techniques.

Thanks, agreed, that'd be 100% correct then. I was just keeping LLM and GPT without extending the sentence too much in case SE wants to keep these keywords.

@FranckDernoncourt Looking at the pages, there are some places where this could be expanded on. I think the header "What counts as "content generated by generative artificial intelligence tools"?" section makes sense. However, this section could also be expanded to include other types of generative AI that isn't based on LLMs or GPTs.
